# I try many times but can't build graph. How to generate graph on neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, data-visualization

How to generate graph on neo4j? It's little hard if I've more data over 10K

[image: embedded image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where your data is stored.

The easiest way by far is to import data from CSV files.

Check out this tutorial: https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_load_csv_for_medium_sized_datasets

Importing node data from CSV files with Cypher through the Neo4j browser will be something along the lines of:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///people.csv" AS row
CREATE (n:Person {first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, age: row.age})
```